# flatpak fails, seemingly entirely

Tags: ubuntu-mate, flatpak

EDIT (Jan 11): I found "my" workaround (with apologies that it won't help others with the same problem).

The tar.gz distro of the software I want to run works fine, out of the box, on my old Ubuntu 16.04 system (which won't run flatpak either!). Since this is not software I expect to need very often, I'm going to run it there.

Many thanks to everyone who invested their time and energy in helping me with this.

---

I have a piece of software that I want to install that's distributed as a "flatpak". However, after installing the flatpak system in my Ubuntu Mate 20.04 system, it fails to load the package I want to use. I get this error:

```
$ flatpak install chirp-daily-20220103.flatpak 

Note that the directories 

'/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share'
'/home/simon/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share'

are not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, so
applications installed by Flatpak may not appear on your desktop until the
session is restarted.


** (flatpak install:41527): WARNING **: 20:31:39.113: Error unregistering authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.235 was not provided by any .service files
error: Authorization error: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

Further, attempting to list flatpaks doesn't seem to work either, so I don't know what else I can try:

```
$ flatpak search vlc
No matches found
```

The above, as best I understand, should list options for installing vlc.

---

Thanks to all for the efforts to assist. Sadly as of today (Jan 10) there's no improvement. I followed N0rbert's guidance to install / upgrade from the PPA (my original install was directly from the core repos "sudo apt install flatpak"). The installation seemed to work, but on attempting the remote-add, it fails:

```
$ flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

** (flatpak remote-add:37255): WARNING **: 15:10:26.654: Error unregistering authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.139 was not provided by any .service files
error: Authorization error: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

Is this possibly a Mate-specific thing? (I guess I'll try it on one of my other machines that has vanilla Ubuntu 20.04.)

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this an error that only occurs when installing this particular package? If this is the case, please report it on their GitHub page. You could also install this application through a PPA. Your question is currently written in such a way that it lacks specificity and clarity. You must provide all pertinent information so that an appropriate answer can be given.

Comment: I'm entirely unfamiliar with flatpak. I have no reason to think it's a problem with the package, but no way to test that. What would you like me to try?

Comment: Check if some other flatpak package installs properly. For example, try `flatpak install flathub com.rafaelmardojai.Blanket` (Note - I am not affiliated with the development of this software).

Comment: Try running `flatpak update --appstream`

Comment: If you installed flatpak via some method other than Apt, uninstall and follow the steps listed in @N0rbert's answer. It seems like there is something wrong with the wiring here. Behind the scenes, Flatpak has a relatively complex configuration, especiallly where permissions are involved / needed.

Comment: I installed from apt, wasn't trying to be clever on that one...

And update --appstream does nothing, just returns ("instantly") to the command prompt with no visible effect.

Answer (score 5):

Your Flatpak version may be out-of-date. Install [newer](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/) from [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eflatpak/+archive/ubuntu/stable) as follows

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
```

then add default FlatHub remote and retry installation of [Chirp](https://trac.chirp.danplanet.com/chirp_daily/LATEST/):

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://trac.chirp.danplanet.com/chirp_daily/LATEST/chirp-daily-20220103.flatpak
flatpak install chirp-daily-20220103.flatpak
```

Then reboot to get flatpak registered in system, and finally launch CHIRP from Applications or Brisk menu.

Comment: flatpak perfectly installs software within the home directory without `sudo`. It is not required.

Comment: On my test VM `flatpak` command asked for sudoer password two times - for remote and for install. Thanks, @ArchismanPanigrahi .

Comment: I followed these instructions which seemed to be working, but failed at the remote-add part.

Comment: Mint is off-topic here, please use ordinary Ubuntu.